# Can 64 bit java be used with 32 bit tomcat

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I'm getting following error while trying to start my tomcat. So I did some google and it seems it is caused because my tomcat is 32 bit and Java is 64.

Please advice.

```
  [2018-07-12 15:16:18] [error] [21916] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2018-07-12 15:16:19] [error] [21916] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2018-07-12 15:16:19] [error] [21916] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2018-07-12 15:16:19] [error] [21916] ServiceStart returned 1
[2018-07-12 15:16:19] [error] [21916] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2018-07-12 15:16:19] [info]  [ 1760] Run service finished.
[2018-07-12 15:16:19] [info]  [ 1760] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

Comment: Check version of tomcat which you have installed? If it's 32 bit, install a 64 bit version of tomcat.

Comment: 'Can 64 bit java be used with 32 bit tomcat?': No.

Comment: To be clear: Tomcat by itself is pure Java, that can be used with 32 as well as 64-bit Java. But the Tomcat package also have an *optional* Windows Service (Tomcat.exe), which is either 32 or 64 bit. That one must match the JVM bitness.

Answer (score 0):

No, It doesn't. you must use 32 bit java with 32 bit tomcat and 64 bit java with 64 bit tomcat.

See here:https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-windows

Comment: Surely you can come up with a normative (official) reference, rather than arbitrary Internet junk?